# Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink - when run $ ionic start

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am just getting started with ionic, and I am now facing a blocker in a very early step to run ionic.

I am using OS: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64 bit

Node version : v10.0.0 (installed from NVM without root access)

NPM version : 5.6.0 (installed from NVM without root access)

I am following this tutorial:
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/36/Installing-Ionic-2-&-Starting-a-Project

I install ionic by:

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

It returns this:

```
home/brian/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/cordova -> /home/brian/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/home/brian/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/ionic -> /home/brian/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {“os”:“darwin”,“arch”:“any”} (current: {“os”:“linux”,“arch”:“x64”})

    cordova@8.0.0
    ionic@3.20.0
    added 677 packages in 16.679s
```

Then I checked if cordova and ionic is installed by $ ionic -v , and it returns

```
3.20.0
```

I guess it means ionic is installed despite of the WARN message.

I then try to run the next step of tutorial:

```
$ ionic start firstProject blank
```

Then this error show up:

```
? The directory firstProject contains file(s) that could conflict. Would you like to overwrite the directory with this new project? Yes
:heavy_multiplication_x: Creating directory ./firstProject - failed!
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink ‘/home/brian/firstProject/.editorconfig’
```

I have tried to give permission to that path by:

```
$ sudo chown -R brian /home/brian/firstProject/.editorconfig
```

But still, the same error persists when I run $ ionic start firstProject blank

I also have tried running the command using root $ sudo ionic start firstProject blank, but it returns

```
sudo: ionic: command not found.
```

I have tried to install ionic without global attributes, but the result is that it cannot be installed because of that npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3

Has anyone been able to resolve this kind of issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ivander T.P. Try to run the command  npm install -g ionic cordova with sudo  npm install -g ionic cordova

Comment: Hi Nidhin, have tried this but it returns this:
sudo: npm: command not found

Comment: Ivander T.P. can u check whether npm is installed by using npm -v

Comment: Hi Nidhin, yes, it returns 5.6.0

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response Nidhin, I have just solved the problem.

I realized that the folder firstProject was locked. So my recommendation if you want to use node and npm, **better to install it using NVM so you don't install it with root access**.

---

### Let me tell how to recreate the issue

So before I actually install Node and NPM from NVM (Node Version Manager), I first install it from package manager using sudo (root access) using this command ([I followed this reference](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)):

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - 
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Which then causes all my following npm commands should use sudo (for root access).

So, when I run this command ([following this tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/36/Installing-Ionic-2-&-Starting-a-Project)):

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

I was unable to install it:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
```

I need to use root access to install it:

```
$ sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Which then makes ionic and cordova to always run in root access -- I think you should avoid it!

So continue from here, I run the next command following the tutorial:

```
$ ionic start firstProject blank
```

Which then makes the folder /firstProject/ requires a root access (see image attached). And continuing using sudo is not a good idea as sometimes ionic runs another command while running it's process.
[Folder locked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e41Id.png)

In conclusion, the installation of Node and NPM using sudo is not a good idea. I don't know yet if there is a good reason of using sudo, if you know why, please reply a comment.

---

So following my case,

I have actually done it correctly:

1. Install Node and NPM from NVM
2. Install ionic and cordova without sudo (root access)
3. Simply run the ionic start command e.g. ionic start firstProject blank; **but first make sure that there is no existing locked folder with this name** (firstProject).

I hope it helps solve your similar issues.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you elaborate this point 'Install ionic and cordova without sudo (root access)'